# How to display numbers taken from contact and Have Uri

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app which selects the contact from the contacts and display the name and number on the screen. Till now I have created activity to select the contact and the activity is successfully returning the contacts. It is successful in showing the Contact name. Now I have problem in showing the  numbers in it. There are variety of solutions and I want the simplest one. All of them goes through complex methods which is hard for me to understand. I am unable to find a simple function that can display the number like `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME`

Here is my code!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_contact);

    Intent viewContact = getIntent();
    String tempViewContact = viewContact.getStringExtra(MainActivity.contactUri);
    Uri contactUri = Uri.parse(tempViewContact);

    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri,null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int indexName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);

    //Shows Contact name
    String contactName = cursor.getString(indexName);
    contact_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    contact_name.setText(contactName);

    contact_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
    //Now what to do ????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small snippet on how to collect contacts from the device

```
// Getting Content Resolver to Access Contact Details
        ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();

        // Getting Cursor
        Cursor cur1 = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

        // Checking CURSOR HAS DATA
        if (cur1.getCount() > 0) {

            // LOOPING THROUGH EVERY CONTACT
            while (cur1.moveToNext()) {

                // GETTING CONTACT ID
                String id = cur1.getString(cur1
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                // GETTING CONTACT NAME
                String contactName = cur1
                        .getString(cur1
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                String contactNumber = "";

                // Ensuring number availablity
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur1.getString(cur1
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    // Phone numbers are stored in another table

                    // Cursor for Phone Numbers
                    Cursor pCur = cr
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                    null);
                    // Has Number in Cursor - CHECK + LOOP
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                        // Checking Number Count for A SINGLE
                        // CONTACT
                        if (pCur.getCount() > 1) {
                            contactNumber = contactNumber
                                    + ","
                                    + pCur.getString(pCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        } else {
                            contactNumber = pCur
                                    .getString(pCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        }
                    }
                }

                // LOGGING
                Log.d("X", "ID:" + id + "\nName:" + contactName
                        + "\nNumber:" + contactNumber);
                Log.i("X", "--------------------------------");
```

include the below permission in the manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

If you want to show the name and the contact number in a list, then follow the below steps

1) Build a model class with two fields name and contact say ContactModel 
2) Make a ContactModel List and add each model into the list. 
3) Finally attach the data to the listView using a custom adapter.

Comment: Can you explain me this part?

Comment: which part? Accessing contacts or Showing it in the ListView?

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },

Comment: below the comment //Cursor for phone number comment

Comment: The phone numbers are stored in  another table. so first we'll take the Contact ID then we use that id to get the Phone Number of that Contact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77876/discussion-between-ajay-birbal-and-shifar-shifz).